# UPDATE statement for column of multiple rows mapping with another set of rows

Tags: sql, db2

I have the following data:

```
  PGM      INC        EXC
  First    A          AA
  First    B          BB
  First    C          CC
  First    D          DD

  Second   E          EE
  Second   F          FF
  Second   G          GG
  Second   H          HH
```

I would now like to update the column having PGM as 'Second' of the values of INC and EXC of 'First' mapping values correctly.

How do we go about it?

Reedits:

I would like data to reflect as below for PGM = 'Second'

```
  PGM      INC        EXC
  Second   E          AA
  Second   F          BB
  Second   G          CC
  Second   H          DD
```

That is, the columns of Second should reflect the values of column First in the same fashion as has been the values held there.

Answer (score 0):

Didn'ty really understand  your question   but if i am right you  want to update `INC` and `EXC`WHERE  `PGM` is second . if  this is the case

```
UPDATE `table_name` SET `INC` = 'new_value' , `EXC` = 'new_value' WHERE `PGM` = 'Second'
```

This will update every  row with PGM value 'Second' what i suggest you to do is make another field as `id` set is to be auto_increment and index it .

Then you can query like this

```
UPDATE `table_name` SET `INC` = 'new_value' , `EXC` = 'new_value' WHERE `PGM` = 'Second' && `id` = 'id_value'
```

However you can still  query like this for additional conditions

```
UPDATE `table_name` SET `INC` = 'new_value' , `EXC` = 'new_value' WHERE `PGM` = 'Second' && `INC` = 'Old_value' && `EXC` = 'old_value'
```

Comment: Nope that isn't quite what i'd like to see. Please see the reedits.